# Aurelia BrowserSync reload not working for all routes

Tags: aurelia, browser-sync

I am working on an aurelia app and this is the route config

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Title';
    config.map([
      {route: [''], name: 'home', moduleId: 'home', nav: false, title: 'home'},
      {route: 'customers', name: 'customers', moduleId: './pages/customers/customers', nav: false, title: 'customers'},
      {route: 'customers/:id', name: 'custDetail', moduleId: './pages/customers/custDetail', nav: false, title: 'customer Details'}
    ]);
    config.options.pushState = true;
    this.router = router;
  }
```

On a button click from home page, i call

```
 this.router.navigateToRoute('customers', {tags: this.tags});
```

if i modify the customers/:id page, browser reloading doesn't work, shows an error

> Cannot GET /customers/2

Is this how it's suppose to work ?

Thanks !

Comment: so, the problem you're running into is you're at `localhost:9000/customers/2` when you want to be at `localhost:9000/#/customers/2`. From your code here, I'm not sure why. I don't fully understand what page you're on when you modify the `custDetail` page.

Comment: I tried to put     config.options.hashChange = false; but then its going to home page when i try localhost:9000/#/customers/2

Comment: i removed the line config.options.pushState = true and it's all working now. It's showing the # now ,So when should we use the above line ?

Comment: ah! i didn't notice you had push state in there! that would be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your server is not configured to use `pushState`, a special mode that avoids using the url hash for routing. (As we discussed in comments), the following line is what is causing the trouble.

```
// this should only be used when you have a pushState enabled server
config.options.pushState = true;
```

You can either remove it or set it to false.

Comment: So do i need to set it to true in Production ? Or leave it false ?

Comment: leave it false. its kind one of those "most users don't need to worry about it" things.